# Android https api with untrusted certificate

Tags: android, api, https

Hi I have made an Hybrid application that uses API to get data from server. If I run the application with the debug version all works, but if I certified my app and tries to login I received a response status -1. I think that it may be possible because of the https is not trusted. Is it true?